# Using an iterator to print integers

Tags: python, list, printing, iterator

What I want to do is print the integers 0 through 5 in the code below but all I get is an address of the iterator?

```
def main():

    l = []
    for i in range(0,5):
        l.append(i)

    it = iter(l)

    for i in range(0,5):
        print it
        it.next()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Just so you know, calling `next()` returns the next value in the iterator.  So the loop body should read `print it.next()`.

Comment: Quick way to produce your iterator: it = iter(range(5))

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To access the values returned by an iterator, you use the [next()](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#next) method of the iterator like so:

```
try:
    while True:
        val = it.next()
        print(val)
except StopIteration:
    print("Iteration done.")
```

next() has both the purpose of advancing the iterator and returning the next element. StopIteration is thrown when iteration is done.

Since this is quite cumbersome, all of this is wrapped nicely up in the for-syntax:

```
for i in it:
    print(i)
print("Iteration done.")
```

More links:

- [Python documentation on iterator.](http://docs.python.org/glossary.html#term-iterator)

Comment: On the first code block, is it possible to not include the try statement?

Comment: Yes, but then the exception will be thrown further up.

Comment: looks like in version 3 (or so) you need to change next to __next__

Comment: @kdubs I believe the Pythonic way is to [`next(it)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) rather than `it.__next__()`. By the way, `__` means **bold** in [Markdown](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#italics-bold).

Answer (score 3):

When you have an iterator, you have to iterate over it, not over a range.

```
for i in it:
    print(i)
```

Comment: Is there a way to dereference an iterator like in C++ using *it?

Comment: No, Python doesn't use pointers at all. And why would you want to? Dereferencing is used to get a value, and Python already hands you that value. Try not to think in C++ terms at all when working with Python.

Comment: Python `it.next()` is roughly equivalent to C++ `*it++`. You don't get to separate the operations.

Answer (score 3):

When you are using the for loop, you are actually calling the iterator object's `__next__` method implicitly. So, you would just not use something like range, but instead just use iterator itself.

```
for i in it:
    print i
```

For what it is worth, `xrange` in Python 2 and `range` in Python 3 returns an iterator, so you just write your first loop with those to have your desired solution,